# clustering customers in R: proper profiling, chooshing the variables & visualizaion

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

Can I please ask the community for the help, to understand what steps should I make in clustering my customers.

The objective is to create the basis strategic segmentation.
We’ve got the plenty of the customers, I’ve prepared the test sample (very small) to learn my way towards segmentation creation.

So I’m using k-means clustering as a start, I’m scaling the dataset, to obtain the normalized data.
I’m getting the relevant number of clusters (7 or 8) on a test sample of 100K consumers.

But what I’m failing to do are these questions. Can you please help me in achieving this? I’m familiar with the theory (run through theoretical course @ the "Customer segmentation using SAS", but it was >10 years  ago, and I had no on-hands experience, trying to catch up now, using R)

1. I’ve got the segments, and the means for each of them, to properly profile them – but it’s using the scaled variables. How can I add the means of each of the segments, using non-scaled, original values, to have more business value while profiling them?
2. For the distribution of each of the variables – how can I efficiently compare non-normalized vs normalized values using histograms? For each of the segment, vs average in the database, to show the difference?
3. How can I (and should I?) strip the outliers in the most efficient way here in R

```
main_kpis <- read.csv("main_kpis_1year_test_500.csv") 
main_kpis <- select(main_kpis,1:10,13:17)
str(main_kpis)

h<- hist(main_kpis$count_active_days_with_drop_or_dep,breaks = 110); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$breaks, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$sum_drop,breaks = 20); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$breaks, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$sum_dep,breaks = 20); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$breaks, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$ggr,breaks = 150); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$breaks, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$avg_dep,breaks = 150, xlim=c(0,10000)); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$counts, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$avg_drop,breaks = 100, xlim=c(0,10000)); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$breaks, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$age_years,breaks = 50,xlim=c(17,70)); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$breaks, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$income_score,breaks = 12); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$breaks, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
h<- hist(main_kpis$number_of_days_no_bet,breaks = 20); h; text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$mids, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))

mdf= names(main_kpis) %in% c("id","reg_date","j11_crm","j56_last_bet","mnclass")
main_kpis_num=main_kpis[!mdf]
str(main_kpis_num)
kpis_scaled<-scale(main_kpis_num)

# kmeans
# optimal numer of clusters 
wssplot <- function(kpis_scaled, nc=20, seed=123){
  wss <- (nrow(kpis_scaled)-1)*sum(apply(kpis_scaled,2,var))
  for (i in 2:nc){
    set.seed(seed)
    wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(kpis_scaled, centers=i)$withinss)}
  plot(1:nc, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of groups",
       ylab="Sum of squares within a group")}

wssplot(input, nc = 20)

#plotting the clusters
library("factoextra")
km.clusters<-km.out$cluster
fviz_cluster(list(data=kpis_scaled,cluster=km.clusters))


#describing the clusters
km.out<-kmeans(kpis_scaled, centers=8,nstart=50)
print(km.out)
```

Sample of my database:
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/EMLUW33BhnAZfA

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Modified and stripped, thanks.